# How to bind to MessageSender in an Azure function?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm working with a service bus queue and an Azure function. Failures are handled differently depending on some business logic. Some messages needs to sent to the dead letter queue, others need to be modified then explicitly added back to the queue.

Consider the following code:

```cs
[FunctionName("ServiceBusTask")]
public static async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myQueue", Connection = "myConnectionString")]
    Message message, 
    MessageReceiver messageReceiver, 
    //MessageSender messageSender, 
    ILogger log)
{
    //some business logic that can fail

    if( condition for dead letter)
    {
        await messageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
    else if( condition for a manual retry)
    {
        QueueClient qc = new Queueclient("myQueue", "myConnectionString");
        Message updatedMessage = GetUpdatedMessage(message);
        await qc.SendAsync(updatedMessage);
        //await messageSender.SendAsync(updatedMessage);
    }
}
```

The messageReceiver works just fine to send messages to the dead letter queue but it bothers me that I need to create a `QueueClient` to send messages to the queue. Knowing that `MessageSender` exists, I tried to add it to the parameters but I'm getting an error saying:

> Cannot bind parameter 'messageSender' to type MessageSender. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

I'm not too sure why it's telling me about startup code, I have no such thing so I'm guessing the error message wasn't updated...

Reading [this issue on the Azure webjobs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1743), I get the impression that it should be supported (do correct me if I'm reading it wrong!).

**My question**

Is it possible to use `MessageSender` like this and if so, what do I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is using a `ServiceBusTrigger`, which supports `MessageReceiver`, but not the `MessageSender` binding - that's supported by the `ServiceBus` output binding, which you could add to your function. ([example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/b9c8afd097ea270f693b1f1e897c14e27b838eec/test/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.EndToEndTests/ServiceBusEndToEndTests.cs#L376))

Comment: That works, though it seems to have a weird behavior where sending a message to the same queue doesn't seem to let Azure mark the current one as completed. Might just be a problem in my logic though.

Comment: how do we set the properties with messagesender?